# Multiple word search and match using RegEx

Tags: php, regex, function

I've created a function that highlights single words within a string.  It looks like this:

```
function highlight($input, $keywords) {

    preg_match_all('~[\w\'"-]+~', $keywords, $match);

    if(!$match) { return $input; }

    $result = '~\\b(' . implode('|', $match[0]) . ')\\b~i';

    return preg_replace($result, '<strong>$0</strong>', $input);

}
```

I need the function to work with an array of different words supporting a space in the search.

Example:

`$search = array("this needs", "here", "can high-light the text");`

`$string = "This needs to be in here so that the search variable can high-light the text";`

`echo highlight($string, $search);`

Here's what I have so far to amend the function to work how I need it to:

```
function highlight($input, $keywords) {

    foreach($keywords as $keyword) {

        preg_match_all('~[\w\'"-]+~', $keyword, $match);

        if(!$match) { return $input; }

        $result = '~\\b(' . implode('|', $match[0]) . ')\\b~i';

        $output .= preg_replace($result, '<strong>$0</strong>', $keyword);

    }

    return $output;

}
```

Obviously this doesn't work and I'm not sure how to get this to work (regular expression are not my strong point).

Another point that may be a problem, how would the function deal with a multiple match? Such as `$search = array("in here", "here so");` as the result would be something like:

`This needs to be <strong>in <strong>here</strong> so</strong> that the search variable can high-light the text`

But this needs to be:

`This needs to be <strong>in here so</strong> that the search variable can high-light the text`

Comment: I could be wrong since Regular Expressions aren't a strong suit for me either, but shouldn't it be $1 instead of $0?

Comment: I really couldn't answer that for you @maiorano84 but I can tell you that the function at the top of this question works correctly using the following syntax: `echo highlight("Good morning and hello world.", "morning hello");`

Comment: Then chances are good that particular portion is correct. Upvote in the hopes you get your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Description

Can you take your array of terms and join them with a regex or statement `|` then nest them into a string. The `\b`'s would help ensure you're not capturing word fragments.

`\b(this needs|here|can high-light the text)\b`

[image]

Then run this as a replacement using the capture group `\1`?

## Example

I'm not real familiar  with Python, but in PHP I'd do something like this:

```
<?php
$sourcestring="This needs to be in here so that the search variable can high-light the text";
echo preg_replace('/\b(this needs|here|can high-light the text)\b/i','<strong>\1</strong>',$sourcestring);
?>

$sourcestring after replacement:
<strong>This needs</strong> to be in <strong>here</strong> so that the search variable <strong>can high-light the text</strong>
```

Comment: Great answer, and much simpler than I would have first thought!

Comment: Thanks for the kind words :)